# Why is “la/le” used more often than “un/une” for noun definitions?

Tags: genre, articles

In English when defining a noun, it is typical to use indefinite article. For example **an apple** or **a bicycle**. Because we're talking about apples and bicycles in general, not meaning any in particular. In fact it would not make any sense if I see noun definition accompanied with definite article.

But in French I see more often noun definitions starting with *le/la*. In the book [Oxford take off in French](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198602995) in particular, every new noun is introduced with **definite** article which doesn't make any sense to me.

**Conclusion**
Thank you all for your answers! You helped me to solve my doubts.
Below, I will outline the most important answers that I completely agree with.

1. @Dave said:

   > My best guess would be
   >   that it make it a lot easier to actually hear the gender: "un" and
   >   "une" sound frighteningly close, especially if you have a non-French
   >   accent and tend to pronounce the 'n' at the end of words...
2. @Argalatyr said:

   > Going from le / la to les is smoother than going from un / une to des.
   >   The latter requires knowledge of the usage of de, and to a novice that
   >   would be a leap.
3. And rephrasing @subtenante (however it doesn't directly answers the question):

   > Indefinite article is better since it doesn't cause the elision when
   >   followed by a word that begins with a vowel or silent *'h'*.

Comment: Thinking about it, I realize that I use _un/une_ myself when correcting others; and I wonder too why people would prefer to use _le/la_.

Comment: Dictionnaries don't use an article to specify the gender.

Comment: Actually, I didn't mention dictionaries. I mean in general, in most of the books. I even specified particular one.

Comment: Although there might be a trend, I think it's a very weak one. As @Joubarc points out, when *correcting* someone, I'd naturally tend to use "un/une" (for the reason you mention in your own question)... As for why "le/la" is preferred in general, my best guess would be that it make it *a lot* easier to actually hear the gender: "un" and "une" sound frighteningly close, especially if you have a non-French accent and tend to pronounce the 'n' at the end of words...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instructional vocabularies routinely include plural forms, and it is simpler to list those using the definite article.  Going from **le** / **la** to **les** is smoother than going from **un** / **une** to **des**.  The latter requires knowledge of the usage of **de**, and to a novice that would be a leap.

Answer (score 9):

I highly doubt that using "le/la" is a common practice, and am sure that is it not a good practice, only by the fact that a lot of names begin with a vowel (or a silent *h*), and thus have the same article for masculine and feminine.

As a few examples, guess if these names are masculine or feminine...

> L'armoire, l'histoire, l'entonnoir, etc.

*Un/une* is better because the elision is not done with *une* :

> Une armoire, une histoire, un entonnoir, etc.

I wonder how the *Oxford take off in French* book deals with these names.

Anyway, "serious" dictionaries do not use a repetition of the name with an article, but use a specific notation instead, for example *[n.f]* for feminine nouns and *[n.m]* for masculine nouns.